# Model of Pen S of Samsung Galaxy Book Pro 360

Tags: laptop

I noticed that there are many types of the Samsung Pen S models. Can you tell me the model of the one associated with the notebook Samsung Galaxy Book Pro 360 please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about compatibility, and as far as I know, it is not allowed yet

Comment: Hello @Irsu85 why it is about compatibility? I'm just asking the name of the model of a specific pen.

Comment: Oh sorry, misread, I will reopen it for you. Sorry :(